# Smooth Scrolling Issues with MathView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an android app where I need to display **maths equations** within a `RecyclerView`. I tried using libraries like [Katex](https://github.com/lingarajsankaravelu/Katex) and [MathView](https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView) to display maths equations inside `recyclerview` but they are slow when scrolling. I know they extend `webview` to display these equations, which is likely the reason for the slowdown.

However, are there any other methods or tweaks to display these maths equation inside `recyclerview` without any performance issue or without making all my contents inside a non-scrollable `webview`.

Comment: Maybe you could render the custom view to a `Bitmap` and display the bitmaps in the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I used images to display maths equation. But, recently I wanted have the option for different font sizes.

Comment: You could generate new images when you change font sizes.